# Über die Bedeutung von „nirgendwann“

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Zufällig habe ich heute dieses Wort gebildet, und darüber nachgedacht, ob *nirgendwann* in der deutschen Sprache möglich ist oder nicht. Ich dachte schon, und fragte mich, warum nicht? Es gibt Wörter wie *irgendwo* und *irgendwohin* mit *nirgendwo* und *nirgendwohin*, also soll es dasselbe beim *irgendwann* mit *nirgendwann* sein.

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/nirgendwann) gibt es keinen Treffer bei der Suche nach *nirgendwann*, dann habe ich einfach dieses Wort gegoogelt und ein paar [Bücher](https://www.google.de/search?q=nirgendwann&oq=nirgendwann&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i61j69i60.3367j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=nirgendwann&tbm=bks) gefunden, die es benutzen, und einige davon sind nicht zu alt, um zu sagen, dass das Wort *nirgendwann* archaisch ist oder etwas in der Art, jedoch habe ich ein paar Fragen.

Ist das Wort *nirgendwann* grammatisch korrekt? Wenn schon, was bedeutet dieses Wort? Ist es einfach die Negation *nicht irgendwann* oder ein Synonym für *nie*?

Comment: Wenn es dieses Wort gibt, müsste es nicht, "zu keiner Zeit" bedeuten?

Comment: Poetisch ist doch alles erlaubt. Ich bin zur Zeit ein Fan von *das Kochsendungsbewusstsein*.

Comment: wahrscheinlich hat sich diese schöne Wortschöpfung bisher nicht durchsetzen können, weil die Ausdrucksmöglichkeiten mit den kürzeren Worten "nie" und "niemals" abgedeckt sind. kurios, dass hier zeitliche und örtliche partikel nicht symmetrisch sind, mir fällt jedenfalls keine dem "nie" analoge kürzere Form von "nirgendwo" ein - und "nirgends" ist entweder Dialekt oder passt nicht ins Schema

Comment: richtig interessant wird es wenn man sich mal in anderen Sprachen umsieht: Auf Englisch würde es sehr holprig klingen ("nowhen"?) und wohl als schlicht falsch gelten müssen, während manche slawische Sprachen wunderbar einheitliche Bildungen zulassen z.B. ukr. ніде *nirgendwo* ніколи *nirgendwann* ніхто *nirgendwer*

Comment: @dlatikay, interessante Bemerkung! Auf Italienisch hätte ich Schwierigkeit, *irgendwann* wäre *prima o poi*, *un giorno o l´altro*, *una volta o l´altra*, aber eine Negation, auf Italienisch, kann ich mich nicht vorstellen

Comment: "Grammatikalisch möglich" ist in der deutschen Sprache sicherlich einiges. Die Frage ist, wie sinnvoll die Bildung solcher Wörter ist. Ich erinnere mich daran, dass eine Gruppierung auf satirische Art gegen die Vorgabe protestiert hat, alle Texte "geschlechtsneutral" zu verfassen, indem sie in etwa folgenden Satz auf ein Schild geschrieben hat: "Vor dem Gehen bitte die Stühle und Stühlinnen auf den Tisch oder die Tischin stellen." Grammatikalisch ist das sicherlich korrekt.

Comment: Es gibt die Wörter Ort und Art. Wenn es das Wort Wort gibt, müsste es dann auch auch Wart geben? Was könnte es bedeuten?

Comment: Und wie ist es mit 'nirgendwer'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das Wort *»nirgendwann«* taucht erstmals kurz nach 1850 im deutschen Wortschatz auf, und gehört heute der Frequenzklasse 22 an. Das bedeutet, dass das häufigste Wort der deutschen Sprache (das Wort »der«) ungefähr 2<sup>22</sup>-mal so häufig verwendet wird wie *»nirgendwann«*.

2<sup>22</sup> = 4.194.304, also kommt im Schnitt auf eine Erwähnung von *»nirgendwann«* ungefähr vier Millionen Mal das Wort *»der«*.

Damit ist *»nirgendwann«* ungefähr gleich häufig wie *»nebelgrau«, »deichseln«* oder *»rußfrei«*, was man an diesem [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nirgendwann%2Cnebelgrau%2Cdeichseln%2Cru%C3%9Ffrei&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnirgendwann%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnebelgrau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeichseln%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cru%C3%9Ffrei%3B%2Cc0) auch gut sehen kann:

[image]

**Nicht im Duden?**

Das macht nichts. Erst diese Woche hat der Brockhaus-Verlag bekanntgegeben, dass in der neuen Ausgabe des Duden rund 5000 Wörter enthalten sein werden, die vorher nicht drin standen. All diese Wörter wurden aber vorher schon verwendet, darunter z.B. *pixelig*, das mir schon seit ca. 20 Jahren geläufig ist, oder *futschikato*, ein Wort, das ich schon aus meiner Kindheit kenne (geboren 1965).

**korrekt?**

Ja. Ich wüste nicht, warum es falsch sein sollte.

**was bedeutet dieses Wort?**

Das kommt, wie bei jedem Wort, ganz auf den Kontext an. Ganz generell würde ich sagen, *nirgendwann* ist das temporale Gegenstück zum lokalen *nirgendwo*. Und weil *»nirgendwo«* »an keinem Ort« bedeutet, interpretiere ich *»nirgendwo«* als »zu keiner Zeit«.

Eine mögliche Verwendung:

> Laut dieser Inschrift hätte das Portal nur am 15. Juni 1879 zwischen 17:53 und 18:14 Uhr geöffnet werden können. **Nirgendwann** sonst wäre das möglich. Wenn das stimmt, sind wir um mehr als ein Jahrhundert zu spät.

Answer (score 5):

Das Gegenteil von *irgend* ist *nirgend*. Alle Wörter, die mit *irgend* zusammengesetzt werden können, sind demzufolge auch mit *nirgend* möglich. Der Duden gibt verständlicherweise nicht sämtliche Kombinationen von zusammengesetzten Wörtern an.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Also ist „nirgendwann“ grammatisch korrekt, habe ich richtig verstanden?

Comment: ja, kann man sagen - klingt etwas überbetont; normalerweise wird *gar nicht* oder *nie* gesagt

Comment: perfekt! Du hast mir auch die andere Frage geantwortet!  Alles klar! Danke!

Comment: trotzdem, lexikalisch möglich ist nicht gleichbedeutend mit tauglich für den Sprachgebrauch. In einem alltagssprachlichen Zusammenhang würde "nirgendwann" wohl irritieren oder amüsieren, und mit dem nach diesem Prinzip ebenso zulässigen "nirgendjemand" wird man sicher ein "wie bitte?" ernten.

Comment: Nirgendwann habe ich selbst schon verwendet als prompte Antwort auf eine Terminfrage zum klar machen, dass es nie stattfinden wird

Comment: In der Umgangssprache oder in Dialekten gibt es viele Wörter, die die Leute verwenden, die aber alles andere als Hochdeutsch sind. Laut folgendem Link: http://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,80891 wäre z.B. "nirgendwas" ein Wort, das oft verwendet wird, im offiziellen Hochdeutsch aber nicht zulässig ist und in Schularbeiten als Fehler gilt.

Comment: ja, wenn ich länger darüber nachdenke, ist meine Antwort nicht korrekt in Bezug auf die Verallgemeinerung auf eine Regel. Deswegen werde ich sie hiermit löschen. Es ist aber so, dass nirgendwann ein gültiges Wort ist, wenn vielleicht auch nur in meinem Dialektgebiet und nicht im Hochdeutschen - das kann durchaus sein. Ich bitte aber darum, dass in neuen Antworten zu berücksichtigen.

Comment: Hmm, leider kann eine akzeptierte Antwort von mir nicht mehr gelöscht werden.

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage ist sehr unklar gestellt. Die Bildung von Worten ist eine Frage der Lexikologie und keine Frage der Grammatik. Ob "nirgendwann" grammatisch korrekt ist, kann man also gar nicht sagen.
Stattdessen kann man fragen, ob es 1. verständlich oder 2. gebräuchlich ist.
Die Antworten darauf lauten, dass es qua Analogie zu 'nirgendwo' sicherlich allgemein verständlich ist, aber sehr ungebräuchlich. 
Stilistisch würde man eine Auffälligkeit erzeugen. Je nach Kontext würde wohl mit der Verwendung von "nirgendwann" in der Regel eine Betonung der Absolutheit damit einher gehen, im Sinne von 'keinesfalls', 'unter keinen Umständen', 'niemals'

Answer (score 0):

> ... ob ... in der deutschen Sprache möglich ist oder nicht.

Natürlich ist es in jeder Sprache möglich, Begriffe zu kreieren, die die meisten Muttersprachler sofort verstehen würden, obwohl es diese Begriffe noch niemand verwendet hat.

Beispiele: "Kaufmannin", "Feuerwehrmännin" oder "Krankenbruder".

> nirgendwann

Das Wort "nirgendwann" würde ich genau so eindordnen wie das Wort "Kaufmannin": Jeder Muttersprachler versteht es, aber ist es auch ein "offizielles" deutsches Wort?

Ich habe mir im Internet eine Liste von Wörtern mit "irgend-" herausgesucht und nachgeschaut, bei welchen dieser Wörter das entsprechende Wort mit "nirgend-" existiert (indem ich in Google danach gesucht habe).

Die Ortsangaben ("irgendwo", "irgendwohin" und "irgendwoher") scheinen die einzigen dieser Wörter zu sein, bei denen das Gegenteil mit "nirgend-" tatsächlich in Gebrauch ist.

Die anderen Wörter scheinen nur in Texten wie Gedichten vorzukommen, die natürlich der künstlerischen Freiheit unterliegen.

In einem der ersten Treffer zu "nirgendwas" heißt es sogar, dass das Wort zwar von den meisten Muttersprachlern verstanden wird, jedoch kein offizielles deutsches Wort ist und somit z.B. in einem Schulaufsatz strenggenommen als Fehler gewertet werden muss.

(http://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,80891)

Daraus schließe ich, dass es keine allgemeingültige Regel gibt, die besagt, dass zu Wörtern, die auf "irgend-" beginnen, auch ein entsprechendes Wort mit "nirgend-" existiert.

---

**Nachtrag**

Im badischen Dialekt werden die Nachsilben "-hin" und "-her" als Vorsilbe dem Verb zugeordnet. (Beispiel: "***Dort*** bin ich auch schon **hin**gegangen." Anstatt: "***Dorthin*** bin ich auch schon gegangen.")

Dies lässt mich vermuten, dass das Wort "*nirgendwoher*" durch Anhängen der Silbe "*-her*" an das bereits existierende Wort "*nirgendwo*" und nicht durch Voranstellen des Buchstabens "n" an das Wort "*irgendwoher*" gebildet wird. (Analog dazu "*nirgendwohin*").

Demnach wäre das Wort "*nirgendwo*" das einzige in ganz Deutschland verwendete Wort, das dadurch gebildet wird, dass "*irgend-*" durch "*nirgend-*" ersetzt wird.

Ich selbst bin übrigens im Badischen aufgewachsen und hatte beim Lesen eines Textes, in dem das Wort "*nirgendwann*" vorkam, Probleme, zu verstehen, dass mit diesem Wort eine Zeit- und keine Ortsangabe gemeint ist.

Je nach dem, welchen Dialekt ein Muttersprachler spricht, ist es folglich möglich, dass er Wörter wie "*nirgendwas*", "*nirgendwer*", "*nirgendwem*" ... nicht oder falsch versteht.

Comment: Richtig: Nirgendein ist die Ausnahme, die die Regel bestätigt. Eine Akzeptanz wäre aber denkbar, falls eine prominente Quelle es versuchen würde einzuschleusen... :-)

Comment: @äüö Ich habe meinen Beitrag etwas überarbeitet...

Answer (score -2):

Ich finde die Idee sehr schön und denke, dass grammatikalisch    nirgendetwas dagegen spricht.
Um die Ausführungen von @dlatikay zu ergänzen:

- Der Entwicklung von "nirgendetwas" steht wohl das umgänglichere
  "nichts" im Wege.
- Wer Nena nicht mag, wird dennoch Probleme haben, ihren Welthit "Irgendwie, irgendwo, irgendwann" zu negieren, ohne dabei sehr holprig zu klingen: "Auf keine Weise, nirgendwo, nie"
- Im Deutschen scheinen nur Verneinungen eine Verkürzung zu erfahren: irgendwo <-> (nirgendwo,) nirgends; irgendwann <-> (nirgendwann,) nie; irgendwie <-> (nirgendwie,) -; irgendetwas <-> (nirgendetwas,) nichts.
- Man könnte es da auch mit den Niederländern halten, die für "irgendwie" und "irgendwo" das Wörtchen "ergens" benutzen, und die Verneinung in beiden Fällen einfach ein n voranstellt, "nergens". "Irgendwann" und "nie" heißen "ooit" und "nooit", und zwischen "etwas" und "irgendetwas" wird, warum auch?, überhaupt nicht unterschieden ("iets"), die Verneinung ist konsequenterweise "niets".

Es wäre schade, wenn sich nirgendjemand weiterführende Gedanken zu dem Thema machen würde. Vielleicht wurde das Thema aber auch schon ausreichend behandelt, und man kann es irgends irgends nachschlagen.

Comment: Dieser Beitrag enthält keine relevante Information zur Frage. Daher -1