# Suffixe "-her" und "-hin" in süddeutschen Dialekten

Tags: dialect

Seit [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36637/%C3%9Cber-die-bedeutung-von-nirgendwann/36650) denke ich über die Wortstellung der beiden Suffixe "-her" und "-hin" in einigen süddeutschen Dialekten nach und hätte dazu einige Fragen:

> *Hochdeutsch*:
>
> **Woher** kommst du?
>
> **Dorthin** fliege ich in meinem Urlaub auch.
>
> *z.B. Badisch:*
>
> **Wo** kommst du **her**?
>
> **Dort** fliege ich in meinem Urlaub auch **hin**.

**Frage 1:**

Wenn ein Zitat einer Person, die einen solchen Dialekt spricht, in einer bundesweit erhältlichen Zeitung abgedruckt wird: Würde die Zeitung die Wortstellung belassen oder ins Hochdeutsche "übersetzen"?

**Frage 2** (*das, was mich am meisten interessiert*):

Meine Vermutung ist, dass es sich hierbei nicht um eine grammatikalische Eigenart, sondern um dialektspezifisches Vokabular handelt:

Die Verben in den beiden süddeutschen Beispielsätzen wären in diesem Fall nicht "*kommen*" und "*fliegen*", sondern "*herkommen*" und "*hinfliegen*".

Ist diese Vermutung korrekt?

**Frage 3:**

Wenn ein Künstler (z.B. Schriftsteller oder Dichter) bewusst nicht hochdeutsch, sondern in einem der betroffenen Dialekte schreibt:

Wo müsste er vor dem Hintergrund von "Frage 2" das Leerzeichen in folgendem (konstruierten) Beispiel setzen?

> Wir müssen nicht lange *schwätzen*:
>
> *Irgendwo* kommen wir *her*, aber wir werden **dorthin gehen** / **dort hingehen**.

Comment: Ich glaube, die Frage geht von einer irrigen Annahme aus: "Wo kommst du her?" ist nicht dialektspezifisch, sondern hochdeutsch. Siehe z. B. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herkommen), Beispiel 2.

Comment: @IQV: Und wie sieht es mit "*Dort gehe ich hin.*" aus?

Comment: @MartinRosenau ebenso.

Comment: Ich war bei der gesamten Frage überrascht, dass die Trennung dieser Wörter dialektspezifisch sein soll. Für mich war das schon immer "auch" hochdeutsch.

Comment: @IQV vielleicht gibt es dialektspezifische *Präferenzen*? Schwäbisch sozialisiert neige ich dazu, "hin" bzw. "her" enger and Verb zu binden. Also "dort hingehen" statt "dorthin gehen".

Comment: @Stephie Aber Martin geht laut seiner Frage vom Gegenteil aus, also der Trennung der Wörter. Und badisch und schwäbisch sollten bei diesem Thema nicht wo weit auseinander sein?

Comment: @IQV nicht ganz? Aber egal, wenn ich eine belastbare Antwort hätte, würde ich sie posten.

Comment: Ich wage die These, dass es im badisch/schwäbischen Dialekt *hin* eher nicht gibt (man sagt *na* oder *ahne* und *nab* statt *hinab* bzw. *nuff* statt *hinauf*), das ändert aber nichts and der Trennung (*Wo gosch na?*).

Comment: Duden behauptet schon, dass "hin" als abgetrennter Teil von Adverbien umgangssprachlich sei: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hin#Bedeutung5 - Martins Annahme scheint entgegen meiner Erwartung richtig zu sein. Ich bin aber ein bißchen hin- und hergerissen (sic), ob die genannten Beispiele nicht alle auf ein trennbares Verb zurückzuführen sein könnten (*hingehen/wo* vs. *gehen/wohin*).

Comment: @IQV: Ich gehe schon davon aus, dass das, was Steffi sagt, stimmt: Aus "Dort hingehen" kann man sich schließlich die Wortstellung "Dort gehe ich hin" erklären, was mit "dorthin gehen" nicht möglich ist. Ich bin nur überrascht, dass dies auch im Hochdeutschen vorkommt.

Comment: @Takkat Korrekt. Wobei es bei uns "no" oder "noa" ausgesprochen würde.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selbst Wörterbücher scheinen sich hier nicht ganz im Klaren zu sein:

Im Online-Duden findet sich unter *hin* eine **regionalsprachliche** Verwendung mit dem Beispielsatz

> Wo gehst du hin?

unter *hingehen* dagegen findet man **standarddeutsch** ein trennbares Verb vor, das uns den Beispielsatz

> Wo gehst du hin?

(also genau denselben) beschert.

Die beiden Sätze unterscheiden sich für mich in nichts, außer der jeweiligen grammatikalischen Interpretation. Ich bin mir daher nicht so ganz sicher, ob denn deine Grundannahme der Regionalsprachlichkeit so richtig ist (was den Rest deiner Frage [sic] einigermaßen in Frage stellt)

Ich denke das beantwortet deine **Frage 1** mit nein, er würde es nicht ändern, sondern alls trennbares Verb interpretieren können und daher für standardsprachlich halten,

deine **Frage 2** mit Ich halte deine Beispiele nicht für süddeutsch-spezifisch, sondern standardsprachlich,

und deine **Frage 3** mit: Es hängt natürlich davon ab, welchen sprachlichen Hintergrund der Autor seiner Figur unterstellt - Ein Schwarzwälder Bauer würde ziemlich sicher "dort hingehen" sagen, ein Norddeutscher Küstenfischer könnte meiner Meinung nach (bewege mich hier bewußt auf dünnem Eis) sowohl "dort hingehen" als auch "dorthin gehen" sagen.

Mit der Annahme, ein trennbares Verb  vor sich zu haben, sind für mich

> dahin gehen

und

> da hingehen

beide richtig und beide standardsprachlich.

> da hin gehen

wäre allerdings falsch.

Noch ein bißchen in den süddeutschen Dialekten gebuddelt, kommt für mich ein kleiner, aber feiner Unterschied zu Tage, wenn man

> Wo gehsch du nauf?

und

> Wonauf gehsch du?

vergleicht, die beide in meinem Dialekt möglich sind - Das erste würde ich verwenden, wenn ich fragen würde, ob jemand die vordere oder die hintere Treppe nimmt, das zweite für die Frage nach dem Ziel: Tenne oder Hochstand. Im Hochdeutschen vermag ich diesen Unterschied aber nicht auszudrücken, und für "hin" gibt es ihn, glaube ich, auch nicht.

Comment: So viele schöne Kalauer! :D

Comment: Ob das Verb "hingehen" nun dialektspezifisch ist oder in ganz Deutschland vorkommt, war mir weniger wichtig. Wichtig war mir die Frage, ob "hingehen" nun tatsächlich ein trennbares Verb ist, oder ob hier irgendein anderer Mechanismus greift. Danke für die Antwort.

Answer (score 4):

Als ehemaliger Redakteur einer - nunja, in Süddeutschland erscheinenden - Tageszeitung wage ich mal folgende Behauptung:

**Zu Frage 1:**

Die Zeitung würde den Wortlaut nicht verändern. "Wohin gehst du?" und "Wo gehst du hin?" sind zwei Varianten, die beide standardsprachlich möglich sind. "Wo gehst du hin?" ist etwas mehr umgangssprachlich, aber eben trotzdem standardsprachlich, nicht etwa dialektal. Dialektal wäre dagegen:

> Wonaa goosch? (Wohin gehst du?)

und

> Wo goosch naa? (Wo gehst du hin?)

Man sieht: die Stellungsvarianten gibt es gleichermaßen im Dialekt wie in der Standardsprache.

**Zu Frage 2:**

Entsprechend würde ich die Vermutung, dass man im Dialekt von anderem Vokabular ausgehen sollte, zurückweisen.

**Zu Frage 3:**

"Irgendwo kommen wir her, aber wir werden dorthin gehen / dort hingehen":

Ein Problem ist, dass der Satz so unnatürlich ist. Ich kann mir weder in der Standardsprache noch im Dialekt ein Szenario vorstellen, wo man so etwas in dieser Weise sagen würde. Aber gut, probieren wir es irgendwie:

> Mir kommet irgendwo her, aber mir wärrat doo naa ganga.

Wenn man sich zur Beantwortung der Frage, wo das Spatium zusetzen wäre, an den prosodischen Merkmalen eines solchen Satzes orientierte, müsst man es eben so wie oben schreiben. Begründung: Sowohl das "doo" als auch das "naa" sind hier Träger betonter Silben ("mir wärrat dóo náa gánga"), wobei ich das Setzen eines Spatiums an der auffälligen Längung der Vokale festmache.

Etwas natürlicher wäre wohl:

> A: Ha, wo kommet jetz iiihr här?
>
> B: Mir kommet von doo, ond mir gangat doo naa. / Mir wellet doo naa ganga. / Mir dent doo naa ganga.